# Is there any side effects changing the SQL Server 'sa' username to something else?

Tags: sql-server, access-control-list

To improve security we thought about deleting or simply changing the 'sa' username, to something like 'imnotsa'.

Will it wreck havoc on our server?

Comment: Please don't ever delete it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do what you are [describing](http://www.andreas-kraus.net/blog/security-advise-rename-your-sql-server-2005-sa-account/).

You may want to run a trace and audit usage of the account to make sure it is not in use.  Some vendor packages use it.  Some application developers will use it when they don't feel like figuring out security.

It's nice to have that account around with a password you know, in case you lock yourself out somehow.

Answer (score 3):

**Do not delete your SA account!**

That being said, not only can you rename or disable it but its RECOMMENDED that you do so.

When you leave the 'sa' user alive and kicking you've just given hackers HALF of what they need to know to gain access to your system.  Most hacking programs out there run by "script kiddies" rely on the fact that 'sa' is your system administrator name and 1433 is your port your server is running on.

Changing the SQL Server port to another non-standard port will reduce the amount of attacks on your server considerably.  Just like changing your ssh port (on Linux servers) from 22 to something else stops many of the brute force attacks.

Changing the port is up to you.  Sometimes its more of a problem than its worth (other software, other developers, etc) but I'll leave that up to you.

Disabling or renaming the 'sa' account is HIGHLY recommended though...

You can easily protect yourself from such attacks by disabling your 'sa' account.

**To disable the 'sa' account:**

```
ALTER LOGIN sa DISABLE;
```

**To rename the 'sa' account:**

```
ALTER LOGIN sa WITH NAME = [yourNewNameHere];
```